# Image pushes extra space right as screen gets more narrow

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a responsive site right now and basically [this is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j91L5.jpg). I want the picture to stay about where it is at 1900px, but for some reason as the screen gets smaller that picture just seems to stay stuck where it is and I have no idea why. I have tried changing everything I can think of. Maybe someone with more experience will see what I'm doing wrong. I feel like I've had this problem before, but I can't remember what I did to fix it.

HTML5

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="content-box">
        <img id="outside" alt="Outside Header" src="images/outside-guy.png">
        <!-- #BeginEditable "content" -->
        <h1 class="center">Add your title here</h1>
        <p>Add your text here</p>
        <!-- #EndEditable -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS 3

```
/* ===== CONTENT AREA ===== */
#content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 2% auto;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    width: 88%;
}
#outside {
    width: 750px;
    position: relative;
        bottom: 65px;
        left: 125px;
}
/* ===== SECTION BLOCKS ===== */
#content-box {
    bottom: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
}
```

I solved the problem by putting a wrapper of 980px around the content area. This allows the image to stay fixed until the media kicks in at that point and a margin: 0 auto on the wrapper pulls the content to the middle of the area. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Can we have an example? (Jsfiddle, codepen, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is because you gave it a fixed width (750 px). Try giving it a % width and see if it resizes properly?

Comment: Yeah I had it like that, but when I do it gives me a whole new set of problems. As the width decreases the image does as well and floats itself up into my header and becomes wayyy too small before the media kicks in.

Comment: @SecretWalrus Oh, so you want it to be size n, except when size n is too small? How about a max-width?

Comment: yeah, a max-width and a min-width so it doesn't become too small?

Comment: can a min width even work with percent? I mean wouldn't it just always become the minimum width as it would resize itself to the width of the browser?

Comment: I didn't mean a min-width as a percent, but as a px value (I'm not sure that it *wouldn't* work with a %, but I'm not sure it would either), just so it doesn't get impossibly small, and then a width as a %, and a max-width as, again, a px value. Also not sure what you're saying in your second sentence...